# Update service data in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-services

Service data object is updated in several components and now how to use last updated value of the object in the first init component. In that component when I init object in *ngOnInit* it doesn't have the last value.

So how can I trigger last change of the object and put it in the component?

In service:
`title: string;`

And in first component:
`appTitle: string;
ngOnInit() {
    this.appTitle = this.titleService.title; // <- here is first init and have default value;
}`

And in second component:
`appTitle: string;
ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.title = 'Login';
    this.appTitle = this.titleService.title; // <- here is first init and have default value;
}`

And in the HTML files of the components, I use simple `{{ appTitle }}`

Now I like in the first component `appTitle` to be 'Login' like last service object update. But I can't achieve it in this way. 
I can't get last update from my second component in the ngOnInit in the frist component.

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) shared services is wha you are after and you need to use `behaviour subject` in services to update the component

Comment: Use Observables and Subscriptions to wait for you component on init till he pulled the newest version of the object. Should be straight forward. If you need a code example, please provide some of you own code and i will try to add a solution.

Comment: Try with https://gist.github.com/jhades/05d6021c271ebeaf5ce3a61ff8d8f44a#file-06-duplicate-calls-fix-ts the explanation http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-rxjs-common-pitfalls/

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem? If you attach your code to question we can help you more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your problem is, but if it some data in your service that you would like to share with other components you can do the following.

Angular 2/4 has built in data-binding, meaning that if you use your service in your components as public, you can manipulate the objects directly, and all other components will have the updated version.

e.g. in your component

```
constructor(public myService:MyService){
 myService.sharedData = {someAttr:"Updated"}; // can also be used directly in your view.
}
```

and in your service:

```
public sharedData:any = {someAttr:"Hello"};
 constructor() {
}
```

and in your html:

```
<body>{{myService.sharedData}}</body> <!--Will display your shared data object-->
```

Comment: Yes, I have register my component as public in app.module.ts, but with this code flow my data in the first component don't update with last change, 'Login', ngOnInit goes before second component and I can't get update of the value that is made in the second component

Comment: don't use `{{appTitle}}` in your html, and remove the local `appTitle: string` from your components. Instead, in your html, write `{{titleService.title}}`. You can use the variable directly instead of declaring a local one in your component.

Comment: Great buddy, that's I want. Thanks a lot, @John. And if you have a time, can you tell me how can also update my local component var.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. If you need a local variable that is in sync with your service, then you need it to be an object (like this `var myVar:any = {myString:""}`), and then it must reference (point to) the object in your service. You will then always work on the same object in all components referencing it. Hope that was understandable. so in your compoent `myObject = myService.myObject`, and in your html: `{{myObject}}`. It is important that the variable is an object, and not a primitive (such as string or number)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a getter:

```
get appTitle()
{
    return this.titleService.title
}
```

now when you call `this.appTitle`, you get fresh title from service.

Comment: I try getter, but problem is that first component ngOnInit occurs before update and I can't get it with this event.

Comment: Do you want to load components sequential? In the other word do you want to always load second component after first component?

Comment: Yes, first one is for breadcrumbs and the second one is in the other folder and is about login.

Comment: When you use getter, after first change in your component, it will check for new values. Maybe there is no change/event in your first component, hum?  if so, you may need to force angular to re-check the values

Comment: constructor(protected _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

_markForCheck(): void {
    this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}

Comment: In the first component I don't have other changes only in ngOnInit, but how to get change in the service object, it is the same for the two components, and it is updated after first ngOnInit. How can I make observer subscribe for this object?

Comment: And can you explain how to use it? How to pass data object in them?

Comment: You dont need to pass any object to it. just call the `_markForCheck()` whenever you want to angular re-check the values(for current component)